# Can you pull real-world coordinates from models you "drop" into a scene in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

When you have 3D models in a scene in ARKit, can you pull the real-world coordinates from them? Are they maintained anywhere?

Example: I've seen apps where you can drop a 3D couch into a scene. Do you get map coordinates for that couch that you can use in the real world to locate "where" it was placed?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/arkit-fundamentals-in-ios-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties, you would have to mix in the `CoreLocation` library. From there, you could get the Coordinates of the Origin of the scene when ARKit is finished initializing, and then append the appropriate number of meters in the appropriate direction using `node.worldPosition.`

[Check out this project for more](https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation) !